# How to convert from NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970 to NSDate()?

Tags: swift, swift3, nsdate, nscalendar

This is my code. But an error said, cannot invoke dateComponent with an argument list of type...

```
 let fromDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(tweetsArray[indexPath.row].timestamp)!)

        let toDate = NSDate()

        let components : NSCalendar.Unit = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth]

        let differenceOfDate = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: fromDate, to: toDate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3, `NSCalendar.current` returns a `Calendar`, which is the
Swift value wrapper type for the Foundation `NSCalendar` type.

`dateComponents()` takes a `Set<Calendar.Component>` and two `Date`  arguments. `Date` is the Swift value wrapper type for `NSDate`.

When existing Foundation APIs are imported into Swift, the types are bridged automatically, that why `NSCalendar.current`
returns a `Calender` and not `NSCalendar`.

The values types are preferred in Swift 3 because they
provide proper value semantics and use `let` and `var` instead
of immutable and mutable variants.

Putting it all together:

```
let fromDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: ...)
let toDate = Date()
let components = Set<Calendar.Component>([.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth])
let differenceOfDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: fromDate, to: toDate)
```

For more information about Swift 3 value wrapper types and 
their corresponding Foundation types, see
[SE-0069 Mutability and Foundation Value Types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0069-swift-mutability-for-foundation.md),
or the section "Bridged Types" in 
[Working with Cocoa Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-ID61) in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" 
reference.