# Error comparing Integers: Binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int'

Tags: swift

I have the following implementation:

```
class MyClass{
 static let sharedInstance = MyClass()
    public var someNumber:Int = 10

    private func doSomething(){

     if self?.someNumber <= 0 {

     }
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to compare if is less or equal to zero I get this error:

[image]

If I try the solution on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630192/error-binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-int-and-in) I get this error:

```
Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Int'
```

Any of you knows how can I fix this error or if there is any work around this?

Comment: why you need self  ? Why not just if someNumber<=0?

Comment: @TusharSharma, if I take the ? for example `if self.someNumber <= 0` I get this error `Value of optional type 'MyClass?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

Comment: Is this simplified?  Is the real code in a closure with weak self?

Comment: I'm seeing this error message: *Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'MyClass'*. Is this the real code? I don't think so.

Comment: @user2924482 i mean to say why you adding self? . I don't see any requirement for calling self.Read this documentation from apple -:https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html

Comment: @user2924482 You use the self property to distinguish between the parameter name and the property name.

Comment: @user2924482 This should be used as a singleton `if MyClass.sharedInstance.someNumber <= 0 {`

Comment: @user2924482  
 Declaring that method as private you would only be able to call that method from another method or from a computed property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `self?`, it looks like you are not including all of the code.  Perhaps the code is really in a closure with weak self?

It looks as if self is `nil` when you call this.  If so, you need to do something else, like

```
if (self?.someNumber ?? 0) <= 0 {

}
```

This says, that if self is `nil`, then use 0 instead of `someNumber`.  If you always want to use 10, you could use that after the ??.

Or you could `if let` check the value and do something completely different in the `else`.

Comment: Better to cast to strongSelf first because there is a reason that self is or might be nil - see my answer

Comment: @Lou, if it's a closure problem then the check should cover the `MyClass` instance. How can self be nullable? What you are proposing is a nasty workaround, it's a coincidence it somehow worked for OP.

Comment: I'm mostly trying to explain that it could be nil and you have to deal with it (assuming that the code in the question isn't everything)

Comment: @Lou Franco You use the self property to distinguish between the parameter name and the property name.In practice, you don’t need to write self in your code very often. If you don’t explicitly write self, Swift assumes that you are referring to a property or method of the current instance whenever you use a known property or method name within a method.

Comment: You do in a closure.  I think we don't have all of the code.

Comment: self in closure is a complete different road.

Comment: This should be used as a singleton `if MyClass.sharedInstance.someNumber <= 0 {`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to unwrap. `someNumber` is not an optional. Just do:

```
class MyClass{
    static let sharedInstance = MyClass()
    public var someNumber:Int = 10

    private func doSomething() {
        if self.someNumber <= 0 {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I don't I get this error `Value of optional type 'MyClass?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

Comment: What is `MyClass`? It is nowhere in the code you posted?

Comment: @user2924482 doSomething it is an instance method. It can not be nil

Comment: Btw the correct answer would be `if MyClass.sharedInstance.someNumber  <= 0 {`

Comment: Btw declaring that method as private you would only be able to call that method from another method or from a computed property

Answer (score 0):

I think we're missing some code. How can `self` be nullable? This only happens to me when I have some kind of `[weak self]` block. In that case, I recast it first:

```
guard let strongSelf = self else {
    return // Probably this ViewController or object got released after the long running operation
}

if strongSelf.someNumber <= 0 {
     // Do stuff
}
```